# What numbers (irrational) in radicals are expressible as trigonometric rational fraction with only rational multiplies of $\pi$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, trigonometric-polynomials

What irrational expressions $A$ with radicals can be expressed as trigonometric rational fraction (not a series) with only rational multiplies of $\pi$.

Example:

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt5} = \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{10}}{1- \sin\frac{\pi}{10}}$

Is there a general algorithm for such numbers to find such expressions?

UPD: Niven's theorem on Wiki [1] didn't help me to figure it out.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: You realize that your question is too broad? What do you mean by finite trigonometric expressions? Which arguments are you allowed to use in the trigonometric functions? What coefficients can you put before the trigonometric functions? Etc.

Comment: Depending on how exactly you formalize this, a reasonably complete answer might be that those are precisely the numbers which are contained in some cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb Q$, or equivalently (by Kronecker-Weber theorem) in some abelian extension.

Comment: Presumably you don't want something like $x = \tan(\arctan(x))$?

Comment: @BeniBogosel, Yes I do. Thanks to your comment I've refined the question to "trigonometric rational fractions". I think that this is more precise - tell me if it is not.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Yes, I do not.

Comment: So do you only allow trigonometric functions of rational multiples of $\pi$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, Yes, only with rational multiples of $\pi$ - I had the same thought a few hours ago. Thanks - I've refined the question.

Comment: Then Wojowu's comment is a propos.

Comment: Can $\sqrt{17}$ be expressed in this way? Meanwhile, this should be useful for showing some possibilities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals

Comment: @Matt F: Since $\sqrt{17}$ is an algebraic integer with minimal polynomial $x^2-17$ having Galois group of order $2$, thus abelian, the Kronecker-Weber theorem says it is.  In fact, if $w$ is a primitive $17$'th root of unity, $\sqrt{17} = \pm (1+2{w}^{3}+2{w}^{5}+2{w}^{6}+2{w}^{7}+2{w}^{10}+2{w}^{11}+2{w}^{12}+2{w}^{14})$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, very nice! Collecting terms in that expression, I get $\sqrt{17}=-1+4\sin(3\pi/34)-4\sin(5\pi/34)+4\sin(7\pi/34)+4\sin(11\pi/34)$